# How to make the bottom box shadow stretch across the whole header

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow, dropshadow

I recently found out how to have the box shadow show up on only one side of an element, however, it doesn't go the full length of the element, and stops a bit short of the edge of the screen on both sides as shown in the code snippet and image below. Does anyone have a fix to this/is it even possible to make it stretch the whole way across? All help is appreciated.

[image: Example Image]

```css
header {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7.5px -7.5px gray;
}
```

```html
<header>Header Shadow Example</header>
```

Comment: I'd suggest inspecting the element to check what the box actually is, and also check your CSS. you've got -7.5px of spread. Chrome dev tools has a good visualization of what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box-shadow creates the effect on the element itself -- since you have margin from the body, you can use a psuedo:after element with negative left and right values to cover that distance.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

header { 
  position:relative; 
}

header::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px grey;
}
```

```html
<main>
   <header>Header Shadow Example</header>
</main>
```

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward solution

Comment: Perhaps we should use CSS3 syntax `::after`

Comment: @Webber Hmm, didn't know that about pseudo elements! https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-element-syntax

Comment: slightly edited to make a full reproduction of your behaviour. Note that probably `body` or `html` attribute have `margin` or `padding`. I have set it to 0 and explicitly set 15px padding to main, which wraps header.